# How does this Code work? String to Boolean

Tags: string, boolean

I found this piece of code to parse a String into an Boolean value. It works perfectly fine, but I just want to know why it works.

```
 boolean result = Boolean.parseBoolean(new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("javascript").eval(string).toString());
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#parseBoolean-java.lang.String-

Comment: Yeah I know what parseBoolean does, but normally it would only work on one String which contains "true" or "false" but this one works for a more complex String like "true | false | true ^ false &true" and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is acctually quite simple, You get a string representation of your boolean with `new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("javascript").eval(string).toString()` and then you use the static method `Boolean.parseBoolean(String s)` from the Boolean class to convert into a boolean type.

You can look the documentation for the [java.lang.Boolean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html) class if you want.

---

According to the documentation of the static method

> The Boolean returned represents a true value if the string argument is not null and is equal, ignoring case, to the string "true"

In any other cases the static method will return false I think.

Comment: You mean `Boolean.parseBoolean()`.